# eclipse: cannot load workspace

Tags: eclipse, ant

I try to give you a summary of what happened. [...] means that passed some time.

- OS is Linux
- all was working fine
- [...]
- every time I started eclipse I needed to switch workspace even if there was only default workspace in the list of workspaces
- [...]
- I added build.xml following an Ant tutorial to one of my projects
- When I ran it using Ant, it ran out of memory. I turned off eclipse.
- When I restarted eclipse, once switched to correct workspace each of my open files reported:
  `Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class` org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.
- package explorer says: `Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart.`

What's happened? How can I restore it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by manually removing build.xml from project folder and restarting eclipse. Hope this helps.

EDIT: after restarting Linux the problem reappeared.

WORKAROUND: The problem seems to happen after an incorrect shutdown. I found this workaround:

- close eclipse
- restart OS (not sure if is needed)
- manually cut the folder of the project opened in eclipse when incorrect shutdown happened and temporary past it outside workspace (i.e. on desktop)
- restart eclipse
- close eclipse
- restore the project folder into workspace
- restart eclipse

Comment: This sounds like a serious bug. I believe you should report it to the guys: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar problem but in Windows in this Question: ["Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart." issue in adt ( v22.6.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211494/plug-in-org-eclipse-jdt-ui-was-unable-to-load-class-org-eclipse-jdt-internal-ui/23696852#23696852)

Maybe this will help others.