# "Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart." issue in adt ( v22.6.2)

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

I am getting this error in my adt eclipse. I am using the updated version of java. Please somebody help me to solve this issue.

Comment: update your adt like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22524868/1126351

Comment: I am using the updated version of adt.(22.6.2).

Comment: your eclipse plugins and SDK also need to update.

Comment: They are up to date too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the same bug in Eclipse once.

This happened to me after a Windows Update.

What I did to resolve the problem was giving (again) "Full Control"/"Admin Write Read" permissions to Eclipse Folder, in my case was in "C:\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64". (Right Click on it, then Properties -> Security Tab and Edit there at -least your user- with Full Control)

For some reason the Windows Update changed that.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error in eclipse photon. I started photon with older workspace. I removed .metadata and .recommenders folders and then restarted the eclipse. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to switch ownership back to my ID in my workspace/.metadata folder, then all was well. I had inherited an old user ID for my login after a system update. [Ubuntu 14 --> 16]

Answer (score 0):

bro delete the .metadata folder from your ecplipse wookspace folder and it works, and then recover mean import your eclipse folder then all will be same except date lol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).